# Cufon not loading after ajax request on wicket

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, wicket, cufon

I have a listview in my wicket website that is updated dinamically, so I don't need to refresh the entire page. The thing is, when the listview adds rows dinamically the javascript "cufon" seems to stop working and the fonts of my listview change to the standard ones. I'm using wicket 6.2.0. How can I fix this?? Thanks for the help.

Comment: what is this cufon and how do you use it?

Comment: Cufon is a javascript for using nonstandard fonts in a website. This is the website http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Comment: you will need to call Cufon.now() after you added the new rows.

Comment: Still not working, I use in my wicket code:

`AjaxRequestTarget.prependJavaScript("Cufon.now();");`

This goes inside my AjaxLink to add the new rows.

Comment: can you try appendJavaScript()? Don't have an project with me right now to test it.

Comment: The thing is that a need to load a file "js/cufon-yui.js" and I don't exactly know how to do it with appendJavaScript()...